# How can I add a sound file and play it in android app?

Tags: android

```
MediaPlayer sound1 = MediaPlayer.create (Layout2.this, R.raw.1);
sound1.start();
```

I wrote this code but I have an error that the class can not read my file name and can not display it, however I paste it in a new folder in res folder.

Comment: Doesnt it need to be in the `raw` folder?

Comment: It is already in the raw folder

Comment: Change you filename to file1. Your raw files must begin with a non-numeric character.

Answer (score 0):

Just change you filename to file1 and it will be ok. Your `raw` folder files must begin with a non-numeric character. Or it might be confused with a resource id.